# Count two columns in one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns (user_from and user_to) and I need to know how many different users appears in my database. What is a good and fast way to do that?
I'm using PostgreSQL, btw.

Comment: This should be of interest https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct tmp.UserName from 
(
  select distinct user_from as UserName from YourTable
  union 
  select distinct user_To as UserName from YourTable
) as tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query is quite sufficient to get the list of users:

```
select user_from as UserName
from t
union   -- intentional to remove duplicates
select user_To as UserName
from t;
```

If you want the count, then:

```
select count(*)
from (select user_from as UserName
      from t
      union 
      select user_To as UserName
      from t
     ) t;
```